# WIA scanning in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, scanning, wia

I'm using WIA 2.0 to scan images from a HP scanner. The problem is that saved TIFFs are around 9MBs big (A4 page at 300dpi, grayscale). I convert WIA's ImageFile that contains scan in TIFF format to BitmapSource like this:

```
    public static BitmapSource ConvertScannedImage(ImageFile imageFile)
    {
        if (imageFile == null)
            return null;

        // save the image out to a temp file
        string fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

        // this is pretty hokey, but since SaveFile won't overwrite, we
        // need to do something to both guarantee a unique name and
        // also allow SaveFile to write the file
        File.Delete(fileName);

        // now save using the same filename
        imageFile.SaveFile(fileName);

        BitmapFrame img;

        // load the file back in to a WPF type, this is just
        // to get around size issues with large scans
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            img = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

            stream.Close();
        }

        // clean up
        File.Delete(fileName);

        return img;
    }
```

Anybody have an idea how to reduce image size, if possible in-memory (because I have a lsit of scans that you can preview and rotate)? Thanks.

Comment: BTW it is not necessary to close the stream inside the using block, because during dispose the stream gets closed automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use compression. This example Ccitt4 is for black and white fax compression, the compression factor is huge but there are other versions if you want to keep the grey scale.

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;


public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(BitmapSource imageToConvert, ImageFormat formatOfImage)
{
    byte[] buffer;
    try
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            switch (formatOfImage)
            {
                case ImageFormat.Png:
                    var bencoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                    bencoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imageToConvert));
                    bencoder.Save(ms);
                    break;

                case ImageFormat.Tiff:
                    var tencoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
                    tencoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Ccitt4;
                    tencoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imageToConvert));
                    tencoder.Save(ms);
                    break;
            }
            ms.Flush();
            buffer = ms.GetBuffer();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { throw; }

    return buffer;
}
```

Then to write the image

```
doc.SaveDirectory = DestinationDirectoryImages;
doc.Filename = fName;
doc.Image = ImageConversion.ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(img.Image, ImageFormat.Tiff);
```

and the implementation of .Image is...

```
private byte[] _image;
/// <summary>
/// Bytes for Image. Set to null to delete related file.
/// </summary>
public virtual byte[] Image
{
    get
    {
        if (_image == null)
        {
            if (SaveDirectory == null) throw new ValidationException("SaveDirectory not set for DriverDoc");
            string fullFilename = Path.Combine(SaveDirectory, Filename);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullFilename))
                if (File.Exists(fullFilename))
                    _image = File.ReadAllBytes(fullFilename);
                else
                    _image = File.ReadAllBytes("Resources\\FileNotFound.bmp");
        }
        return _image;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_image == value) return;
        _image = value;
        if (SaveDirectory == null) throw new ValidationException("SaveDirectory not set for DriverDoc");
        string fullFilename = Path.Combine(SaveDirectory, Filename);
        if (_image != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullFilename))
            {
                _image = value;
                File.WriteAllBytes(fullFilename, _image);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filename) && File.Exists(fullFilename))
                File.Delete(fullFilename);
        }
    }
}
```